# Replacing moment() with dayjs

Tags: cypress, locale, dayjs

I'm having problems with the locale when going from the deprecated Moment to DayJS in Cypress.

The original `Moment()` usage:

```js
public moment(): Moment {
    const moment = Cypress.moment();
    moment.locale("nb-NO");
    return moment;
}

const in2Months = moment().add(2, "months");
```

This worked fine, and for instance "March" was replaced by "Mars".

However, when trying to use it the same way with days.js, the locale isn't changed:

```js
public day() {        
    return dayjs().locale('nb-NO');
}

const in2Months = page.day().add(2, "months");
```

The result here is still "March". I've tried using just 'no' for the locale, with the same result.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:
As per the below answer:

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import 'dayjs/locale/nb'

const in2Months = dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month');

cy.log(in2monthstoString());

RESULT: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 12:39:29 GMT
```

...which is not in locale format.

Also, trying any variation of `.month()` I am always getting results in the number of the month. But I cannot get the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Days JS github readme](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs#i18n), you have to import the internationalisation that you intent to use, it will not be included by default. So I wrote a simple program to check this and it worked

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
import 'dayjs/locale/nb'

describe('SO Ques', () => {
  it('SO Ques', () => {
    cy.log(dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('MMMM'))
  })
})
```

Test Runner:

[image: test runner screenshot]

So your program should look like:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
import 'dayjs/locale/nb'

public day() {        
    return dayjs().locale('nb');
}
const in2Months = page.day().add(2, 'Month').format('MMMM');
```

You can evaluate all the values in a function and then return it and then use it in your test like this:

```js
function date() {
    return {
        day: dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('DD'),
        month: dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('MMMM'),
        year: dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('YYYY'),
    };
}

date().day //28
date().month //mars
date().year //2022
```

Comment: const dayjs = require('dayjs') is javascript, isn't it? I'm using typescript, so that command gives an error.

Comment: You can replace `const dayjs = require('dayjs')` with `import * as dayjs from 'dayjs'` for typescript

Comment: You can change `.format('MMMM')` to anything as per your liking. You can check out this - https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format

Comment: Could you see the update, please? I'm not getting the "intuitivity" of this at all.

Comment: What do you want in the variable to be saved `in2Months` ?

Comment: The whole date - day, month and year. And I need to be able to extract the day (number), month (name) and year from it. It's part of a test that dynamically sets the date in the future, and then later uses each part of the date to select and fill in on the page.

Comment: Can you mention in the question. First what exact format of whole date you want in `in2Months` and then from that how do you want to extract the parts of the date?

Comment: When creating the object, I want today's date PLUS 2 months in an object containing the year, month and day. (Adding 2 months works fine). And I need it in localized format, since the page where the day, date and year is selected is not in English. On that page, I need to extract the day, month name and year from the dayjs object. The EXACT format of the entire date object is not important, as I need to extract each part (day, month name, year) separately.

Comment: You can do something like this - `dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('MMMM D, YYYY')`. This will print `mars 28, 2022` localised format. You can play around with more formats here - https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format#list-of-localized-formats

Comment: Thanks. That works for the whole string. But then I want to be able to create a variable in2Months = dayjs().locale('nb').add(2, 'Month').format('MMMM D, YYYY'), and then do something like in2Mothns.month() and get "mars". That doesn't work, since the variable is now a string. With Moment(), I had an object, which I could do these operations on. I can, of course, get the substring, but it seems not very elegant.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can have a look.

Comment: Ah, nice. Does the trick :-)